# query on result aggregation elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I had imported millions data into elasticsearch. Mapping is following:

"_source": {
            "mt": "w",
            "hour": 1
           }

i want to find number of hour's that have occured more than 5.

for exmple:
using terms aggregation i get following result :

"aggregations": {

```
    "hours": {

        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 1,
                "doc_count": 7
            },
            {
                "key": 4,
                "doc_count": 5
            },
            {
                "key": 5,
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do i find count of hour's that occure more than 5.
in here it be 1 because only hour=1 is more than 5

Answer (score 0):

you can use "min_doc_count": 5 in terms aggregation [Elastic doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4)

Comment: tnx, but "min_doc_count" only show results that more than 5 but i count of this results without showing them

Comment: i want size of hours.buckets